# Magento CMS pages — getting title from URL key/identifier?

Tags: magento

Is there any way to get the title of a cms page, if you only know it's url key/identifier? For example, the about page (in the sample data) has a url key/identifier of 'about-magento-demo-store'. If that's the only information I had, how would I go about getting the page title from that? As in the faux code below:

```
$pageTitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->loadByAttribute('identifier', 'about-magento-demo-store')->getTitle();
```

I'd like to get a list of all CMS page titles, using just the url keys/identifiers.

I know you can get the current CMS page title using the following:

```
$pageTitle = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, figured it out myself using trial and error:

```
$pageTitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('about-magento-demo-store', 'identifier')->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 8):

I made this solution to get URL-Key (Identifier) of a page:

```
<?php $pageTitle = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>
<?php if ($pageTitle=='home'):?>
```